# How to re-arrange the payload1 with the corresponding values of payload2

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I am new to Mule and struggling with a scenario.

Payload1 is retrieved from a csv file and payload2 is an incoming payload; Payload2 might have more than one object. The output fields need to be arranged according to the payload1 (i.e. csv format) with the corresponding values of the payload2. The comparison needs to be done in all lowercase.

```
payload1 = "Name,Roll Number,Standard,Name of School,Address,Marks in Maths"   //this is an input from a csv file

//below is the input from different payload which is in camelcase.
payload2 = [
  {
    "address": "Street 123",
    "standard": "IV",
    "marksInMaths": "90",
    "rollNumber": "5",
    "name": "XYZ",
    "nameofSchool": "Best School"
}]
```

Required output:

```
[{
   "Name" : "XYZ",
   "Roll Number": "5",
   "Standard" : "IV",
   "Name of School": "Best School", 
   "Address": "Street 123",
   "Marks in Maths": "90"
}]
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I found some issues trying to match the names on the CSV to the ones in the payload2 object. For example, `Name of School` is easy to convert to `nameofSchool`. But to convert `Marks in Maths` to `marksInMaths` the logic is different (unless it's a typo). If the case is like this, you need somewhere the metadata about mapping of the names.

Comment: hi @JorgeGarcia yes, that is the issue; that is why we need to convert both to all lower cases and then do the comparison, only then it will work

Comment: Oh, I got it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the mapping, you need to pay attention to how you read the CSV. If you don't disable the headers in the CSV reader (mime-type attributes on the read operation), the payload will be an empty collection (because you have a collection of objects with no object, just the name of the fields as metadata). Another option is to read the CSV as plain/text and then use splitBy function to get an array of names.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

// Be aware that I disable the headers to get them as values. If not it is not possible with CSV. Another way is to read it as text and then use splitBy
var payload1 = read("Name,Roll Number,Standard,Name of School,Address,Marks in Maths", "application/csv", {header: false})

var payload2 = [
  {
    "address": "Street 123",
    "standard": "IV",
    "marksInMaths": "90",
    "rollNumber": "5",
    "name": "XYZ",
    "nameofSchool": "Best School"
}]

// remove spaces and apply lowercase
fun normalize(value:String) = lower(dw::core::Strings::remove(value," "))
fun normalize(value:Object) = 
    value mapObject ((value, key, index) -> {(normalize(key)): value})


var namesMap = payload1[0] mapObject (value, key, index) -> 
    (normalize(value)): value
---

payload2 map ((item, index) -> 
    do {
        var normalizedItem = normalize(item)
        ---
        // iterate the namesMap to get the right order
        namesMap mapObject ((value, key, index) -> 
            // get the key from the namesMap and look the value in the payload2's item
            (value): normalizedItem[key]
        )
    }
```

The magic is creating the namesMap before the mapping so it's easy to create the mapping then.

EDIT: The original code was wrong. It was only matching the single string keys.

Comment: hi @Jorge Garcia; thank you for your response; however, i am getting null as value for some in the output;[
  {
    "Name": "XYZ",
    "Roll Number": null,
    "Standard": "IV",
    "Name of School": null,
    "Address": "Street 123",
    "Marks in Maths": null
  }
]

Comment: I just added to lower the case of payload2 keys :- var lower_payload2 = payload2 map ((value , key ) ->
value mapObject (    lower ($$ )) : $ ). And in the body used lower_payload2 instead of payload2. It it worked. Thank you so much for the help; It worked.

Comment: camelize() maybe useful if we replace the spaces by underscores.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @Mule-Newbie. I corrected the code, now it should be working properly.